# Decrypt and generate PDF - PHP

Tags: php, web-services, pdf, encryption

In the upload process the file is encrypted.

When the user requests the WS to download the file, this is sent to the user in the following format and still encrypted, it will be decrypted on the user side

```
N\u0016\u00bf\u0097\u00f1ep\u00d6I\u00fb\u00a4\u00adt\\\u0011\u00ef\u00bd\u00feTi\u00a7
\u00c3\u009c\u00a3\u00efC\u00b1'\u00e5\u0014 'B;s\u00e7\u000f\u0004\u00e0\u00e8+\u009b\u00cc\u00b7\u0015o
~dS\u0002\u0097\u008d\u00aaE\u0081k\u001b\u00ff\u00ecIp9z\u00b12\u0010\u0000\u0082bE\u0089G\u00d5\u0005
\u000ebT82\u008bB\u00fe\u00a3\u00d2|\u00f6\u003E0\u00c5\u001b\u0012\u008d3\u00ffL\u00d0\f\u00b5\u0088
\u00ce\u00b8n-'\u00eeUc\u0088|A\u003C\u00a7\u00db\u0080F\u00ec\u00bc\u00bf]_dG\u0091\u00c2\u00c8]\u0011
\t\u00f0\u00e9\u00e3\u00c4\u00dcl\u0087\u00b1\u00f3x\u001f\u00c0-\u0014\u00de\u00f0\u00bb\u00ef@\u00b8
\u000e\u00e7\bh\u009bm\u00f1\u00b9N\u00b4\u00ce\u00e3\u0090\u008e\u00c7A\u0087\u00bb\u00b5\u0017A:\u008bS
\u00ec\u001e\u00f5m\u009ab\u00ca\u00b1\u00f2\u0012\u0089*\u00a41(\u009e\u0087o;\u0011p\u00fe\u0098\u0080
\u00d0x:\u00c9VV\u00d48v\u00dd\u001d\u00d9+\u0097o\u00ac+;\u008e$\u0086\u0082Xf\u0083\u00fe\u00ba\u00d6
\u00a5\u00ba\u00c9\u00e8J\u00f4\fUr\u0012\u009f\u00feP\u00e3E9\u00d7!\u00df\u00a7]r\u0080\u00b4:\u0080'x
\u00ca\u0085\u00c0\u0080S\u00f7\u00a20\u009f\u008fAR;\u00db\u00b0\u00fd\u0014\u00e3!MY\u009c0oHH_\u0000
\u00b8`\u00d0w\u00a6\u009a\u00e1^\u00c2#'\u000e\u00c5,\u00b5\u00b5\u00a2\u0013&\u00d8\r\u0090\u001b=
\u00fd\u00aa\u0087\u00f5\u00f6\u00f7\u008c%\u00d7\r+\u00bc\u00de\u0019\u00b0U\u009frh\u00af\u00f7\r\u00a7
\u0085Z\u00c86gg\u00aa\u00e3\u00ee#A\u009e\u0080-\u00b0\u00f2(\u0017\u000f\u001f\u009bvs\u00d7\u00aeh
;\u009a\u00dc\u00f4\u00c1\u00cc\u00c9\u0080\u00abUe\u00a7\u00ba\u00eev\u00a8\u0084k\u0001\u00d9\u00c2I ...........................
```

After the decrypt process, system needs to generate the PDF file again as it was.

I would like to know how to convert this kind of data in a pdf file again w/ content.

Tks

Comment: Did you even use Google to find out what `\u0016` means for example? Where is your code?

Comment: @martinweise the set of \u0016 .. etc is the file encrpyted... Now i need to run the decrypt method and generate the pdf!

Comment: What encryption algorithm did you use?